# mvc3, IIs 7.5, server behind load balancer/firewall, forms authentication redirects to http://[ipaddress of machine]

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, forms-authentication, iis-7.5

hundreds of hits for these keywords, but nothing that is totally relevant.

So my web server is behind a load balancer.  The web site is exposed by SSL.

When I open my logon page https[mydomain]/app/somepage.aspx, I am redirected to http://[ip address of server]/app/somepage.aspx.

I tried the follwing

- Setting the loginurl to https[mydomain]/app/somepage.aspx, doesnt work
- tried fiddling with the binding in iis, but there's an issue that forces us to use appcmd to set the hostname, but nothing works after I set it.

Suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Here's the Failed Req Log that I activated for 302              265. -GENERAL_RESPONSE_HEADERS 
Headers Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Location: http://10.193.38.32/demo/defaulthv.aspx
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET

Comment: and here's what I used to modify the binding  :   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/591597/how-to-assign-a-ssl-certificate-to-iis7-site-from-command-prompt

Comment: you can edit you inital post, rather than add comments.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds more like a load balancer configuration error, or maybe your load balance just isn't capable of forwarding the request using the same url.  It seems like your load balancer is mroe of a proxy, and is creating a new request using only the IP address.  Most decent load balancers should have an option for forwarding the hostname.

This might be more of a Serverfault question because it has more to do with load balancer configuration.