# MVC3 routing(??) problem when making webserver public through a firewall rout

Tags: model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-3, firewall, nat

An internal mvc3 webapp is hosted (iis7) on a local server `localserver/ourwebapp`
We are trying to expose the webapp external through a firewall route:
`www.ourcompany.com/thewebapp` is mapped to `localserver/ourwebapp`.

Nevertheless the route is working, all links in the rendered html still contain `ourwebapp/controller/action`, which of course doesn't work.

Any idea's how to resolve this issue?

Thx!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try adding the www.ourcompany.com to the list of [IIS Bindings for the site](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731692%28WS.10%29.aspx)?

Comment: Doing some searching it seems that your firewall/proxy isn't forwarding the hostname to IIS http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5844781/mvc3-iis-7-5-server-behind-load-balancer-firewall-forms-authentication-redirec Which firewall are you using?