# IIS and Web Server SSL Cert

Tags: iis-7, ssl-certificate, windows-server-2008-r2, thawte

We have a server running Windows 2008 IIS 7.

We have a client that wants to launch 10 microsites, all of which have different domain names and all require SSL.

I have spoken with Thawte and they have suggested a Web Server SSL certification which allows for a single certificate to cover up to 20 domain names using a single IP addrewss. This is great, but to my knowledge IIS will not allow me to use the same SSL cert on more than 2 site instances, especially when both instances are using the same IP address. Am i correct?

Thanks in advance
Al

Answer (score 0):

The GUI will no doubt complain about this, but you can just add the SSL bindings in the applicationHost.config manually `*:443:hostname.com` and use `netsh` to add the ssl certificate to the IP:Port directly.

See this article for both the `appcmd` and `netsh` commands: [How to assign a SSL Certificate to IIS7 Site from Command Prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/591597/how-to-assign-a-ssl-certificate-to-iis7-site-from-command-prompt)

Where is this 20-domain certificate listed? Only ones I see are Single Domain except for the wildcard unlimited subdomains. http://www.thawte.com/ssl/index.html

Answer (score 0):

You need a multiple domain (UCC cert), also called SAN or Subject Alternative Name cert
Each site will have different SSL host headers.

There is a very good article on configuring SSL Host Headers in IIS 7 at 
http://www.sslshopper.com/article-ssl-host-headers-in-iis-7.html